# I want to get the book that has been issued the maximum no. of times

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables called:

1. BookDetails
2. EmployeeBookTokenDetail

Description of tables:

1. BookDetail
   (BookID Primary Key,BookTitle,BookAuthor,LibraryID,Price)
2. EmployeeBookTokenDetail 
   (EmployeeID,BookID ForeignKey)

I don't have tables in my DB. I just wrote query based on logic. So here's my try :

```sql
Select B.BookID From 
    (
    Select B.BookID, Count(EB.BookID) as TotalCount
    From BookDetails B,EmployeeBookTokenDetail EB
    Where EB.BookID=B.BookID
    Group By B.BookID
    )
    Group By B.BookID
    Having TotalCount = Max(TotalCount)
```

Is this code works fine?

Comment: Then you should create the tables and check if the SELECT works as expected.

Comment: No I don't have access to DB. They assign me some queries to write. So, I just wanna know whether this will work or not.

Comment: We don't know because 1) we don't know how the columns are defined, and 2) you did not tell us how the fact that a book "has been issued" is stored in these two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
select BookID from (
select BookID,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalCount desc) AS BookRanking 
from (
Select B.BookID, Count(EB.BookID) as TotalCount 
From BookDetails B,EmployeeBookTokenDetail EB
Where EB.BookID=B.BookID
Group By B.BookID) BooksCount) BooksRanking
where BookRanking = 1;
```

You can also use dense_rank instead of rank depends on your application logic.

Comment: I don't know how Rank function works. But thanks for your effort. Will try this.